# Font Size on Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

If I have a Control, I can know the Font it is using by the Font Property. Now how can I know the average Size of the Font( or lets say I would like to know what would it be the width of the 'M' char)

I know that  Graphics.MeasureString()  would solve my problem but implies creating a graphic object since I'm not in any paint event.. or wouldn't like to use the CreateGraphics. or nothing like that. I'm raising a grid and would like to set my column Width since I have all my columns text information.
(THis is for Winforms..... NOT WPF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there might not be a guaranteed accurate measurement, you can try [TextRenderer.MeasureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb.aspx).

A good post in SO here on "[Accuracy of TextRenderer.MeasureText results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087157/accuracy-of-textrenderer-measuretext-results)"